# How do I access a specific element of a mapping?

Tags: sass

I have the following mapping to contain all of the colours from my theme:

```
$_base-ocean:rgb(13,176,184);
$_base-hover:10%;

$themes: (
    ocean: (
        base: $_base-ocean,
        hover: darken($_base-ocean, $_base-hover)
    )
);
```

I know how to use an `@each` loop to get the key/value information from a mapping, but how can I directly access the value of a mapping without using a loop?  I tried using square brackets like you would in other languages like JavaScript:

```
@each $name, $colors in $themes {
    [data-page="home"] {
        #slider-pagers{
            a.#{$name} {
                background-color: $colors[base]; // <- line 21
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get a syntax error instead:

```
 error sass/test.scss (Line 21: Invalid CSS after "...d-color: $color": expected ";", was "[base];")
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the use the map-get function.  Sass does not provide a special syntax for accessing values of a mapping.

```
@each $name, $colors in $themes {
    [data-page="home"] {
        #slider-pagers{
            a.#{$name} {
                background-color: map-get($colors, base);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you get the following output:

```
[data-page="home"] #slider-pagers a.ocean {
  background-color: #0db0b8;
}
```

Comment: Haven't tested yours, but it looks like I missed this during my lengthy response..

Answer (score 1):

A good practice when using SassScript maps (not "source maps"; those are [different](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html#source_maps)) is to always quote the keys. For example:

```
$site-global: (
    "ocean": (
        "base": $_base-ocean,
        "hover": darken($_base-ocean, $_base-hover)
    )
);
```

In order to be compatible with CSS, Sass interprets some unquoted identifiers (including `ocean`) as color names and translates them internally to color values. When emitting compressed output, Sass will try to produce the smallest possible representation of those colors, which in this case is a hex code. Quoting the keys makes it clear that they should always be strings and should always be emitted with their string values.

Comment: May I ask what modifications would need to be made to rectify the above code? If I understand the above, does this mean I need to create a less colour name string?

Answer (score -1):

Fixed Issue 1 !

It was a case of doing another map-get within a map-get. Once done, I had to reference the default value (this being base). As long as all my default values had a base value this seems to work fine:

```
@each $theme-colour, $color in $site-global {
    [data-page="home"]{
        #slider-pagers a.#{$theme-colour}{
            background-color:map-get(map-get($site-global, $theme-colour), base);
        }
    }
}
```

How it still fails to minify when this code:

```
#{$variable_here}
```

Funny enough this code does not:

```
#slider-pagers a #{$theme-colour}{
```

or

```
#slider-pagers a#{$theme-colour}{
```

Thanks for responding, if anyone knows the is compiling issue that would be great.